# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path') - Multer Error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, multer

I am uploading an image to a folder in uploads via multer package. I am getting an error while testing the route in POSTMAN.

location_model.js

```
const util = require("util");

const locationSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: String,
    latitude: { type: Number, required: true },
    longitude: { type: Number, required: true },
    heightmapImage: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  { bufferCommands: false } //no biffer time limit
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Location", locationSchema);
```

This is the code for my location router while posting new location with image

```
router.post("/", upload.single("heightmapImage"), (req, res, next) => {
  //Model
  console.log(req.file);
  console.log(req.file.path);
  const location = new Location({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    name: req.body.name,
    latitude: req.body.latitude,
    longitude: req.body.longitude,
    heightmapImage: req.file.path
      .replace(/\\/g, "/")
      .substring("public".length),
  });
  location
    .save()
    .then((result) => {
      //save method provided by mongoose, will save in the databas
      console.log(result);
      res.status(201).json({
        //message: "Working POST",
        message: "Created Location successfully",
        createdLocation: {
          name: result.name,
          latitude: result.latitude,
          longitude: result.longitude,
          request: {
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:3000/location/" + result._id,
          },
        },
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: err });
    });
});
```

And this is the error while doing POST in Postman -

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')"
    }
}
```

Comment: Try the accepted solution in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47110048/multer-file-filename-and-file-path-undefined

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I changed it to **req.files**